# Access info of tweet above mention using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I am making a Twitter bot that transcribes video to text, when people mention the bot on a tweet, I want to get the information of the tweet they mentioned me in, could that be possible with Tweepy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use Tweepy for tweet statuses.

Here is the link for it:

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#tweets

Comment: thanks for the answer, what I did was accessing the id of the original tweet and using it so I could access informations of that tweet, my code is below

Comment: tweet_embedded = api.get_status(tweet.in_reply_to_status_id) or for extended tweets: tweet_embedded = api.get_status(tweet.in_reply_to_status_id, tweet_mode = 'extended')